# EF Core: passing connection string to Add-Migration not working

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-standard

I'm working on a .NET Standard application that utilizes Entity Framework Core 3.1.2.  We use code-first migrations at my company.

When I execute `Add-Migration` with a `ConnectionString` parameter as follows:

```
add-migration MyMigration -ConnectionString "data source=servername;persist security info=True;user id=MyUserID;password=MyPassword"
```

I get the following error:

```
    Add-Migration : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ConnectionString'.
At line:1 char:52
+ ... ration ShuntReportConditionIDAndTitleFields -ConnectionString "data s ...
+                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Migration], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Add-Migration
```

Why do I get this error?  [This documentation site](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx) states that -ConnectionString is a valid parameter for the Add-Migration command.  Has something changed with the EF platform?

Comment: Try adding connectionstring in appsettings.json.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation site is for EF 6, and you are using EF Core!

Comment: Thanks.  I understand, but it leaves me speechless that MS would implement this functionality in EF 6 but not in Core.

Comment: Update-Database gets a Connection option in EF Core 5.0